Select Data from Two Tables without a Join (Cartesian Product) in Gorm
I'm trying to select data from two SQL tables without a join. Essentially, I need a Cartesian Product of the two tables. The SQL statement I expect to use is: SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.quantity>100.
I've tried several ways to achieve this, but none of them seem to work. Here are my attempts:

Multiple arguments: db.Table("table1", "table2").Where("table1.quantity>100").Scan(&result)
Result: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.quantity>100 - Only the first table appears in the created statement.

Multiple calls: db.Table("table1").Table("table2").Where("table1.quantity>100").Scan(&result)
Result: SELECT * FROM "table2" WHERE table1.quantity>100 - Only the second table appears in the from clause.

Comma separated: db.Table("table1,table2").Where("table1.quantity>100").Scan(&result)
Result: SELECT * FROM "table1,table2" WHERE table1.quantity>100


None of these approaches give me the Cartesian Product of the two tables with the desired condition. How can I achieve my goal using the appropriate method?

Why don't you want to use a join? FROM t1, t2 is equivalent to FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2 (at least in postgres).

It would be better if you can add and example of your tables and what rows you expect to see with your query. As I can see this 3rd result is the correct expected result from a cartesian query.
